# Is there a standard asp.net authentication authorization login system?

Tags: security, authentication, authorization

Besides what it comes with in 2.0 (the generated aspnetdb.mdf), is there a standard login authorization authentication system for asp.net Internet websites?  One that can plug into a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"the generated aspnetdb.mdf" is the ASP.NET Membership model. You can use it in websites without *the generated aspnetdb.mdf*.

From an article in MSDN called [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx):

> ASP.NET membership gives you a
>   built-in way to validate and store
>   user credentials. ASP.NET membership
>   therefore helps you manage user
>   authentication in your Web sites. You
>   can use ASP.NET membership with
>   ASP.NET Forms authentication or with
>   the ASP.NET login controls to create a
>   complete system for authenticating
>   users.

See my answer and comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835124/how-do-i-change-my-asp-net-membership-database-from-express-to-standard-sql/835185#835185), too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx) to create the required tables/sprocs/views in any sql server db of your choosing. Once you've added the proper connection string and membershhip configuration, you can use all of the membership stuff that was added with .net 2.0

[4 Guys](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304120451/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102208-1.aspx) has a pretty good tutorial on how to implement the membership system, and they cover using aspnet_regsql.exe.

Comment: I saw that from your other response but I couldn't find a lot on it or how to do it, so I thought maybe there was some other standard way of doing it.

Comment: didn't realize you were the same poster :), in any case the 4 guys article is a really good place to start.