# How can I configure membership provider to insert data on my own database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

How can I configure membership provider to insert data on my own database

Comment: whoever voted to close this because its too localized needs to understand this question is relevent to all asp.net developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a custom Membership Provider to use your custom database (if you want to use a completely different database schema) or follow the steps here:

[How Do I Change My ASP.NET Membership Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835124/how-do-i-change-my-asp-net-membership-database-from-express-to-standard-sql)

Comment: This is solved my problem: http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/02/how-to-setup-and-configure-mysql-membership-provider-6-2-2-porting-to-mono-part-2-of-3/#

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom MembershipProvider to deal with a custom authentication system. You have to implement a bunch of methods. Here is an example

```
public class DreemMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
...
   public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
   {
       //your code to insert a user in the db.
   }

   public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
   {
         //your code to check the user and pass against your db 
   }
   ...
}
```

finally you have to set your app to use your membership provider -> in the web.config

Comment: I use mySql database and Asp.net mvc with automatic generated account controller and i have store info about user in mylqs database

Comment: I am not aware of Mysql Membership providers for asp.net (that doesn't mean there isn't one), but a solution would be code your custom authentication system. You just need to write the implementation of the MemberShipProvider methods for  writing and reading from the db

Comment: When you change the membership provider to be your own custom one, all methods from the "generated" account controller will use the methods in your custom MemberShip Provider. I think this is what you want...

Comment: when i for example register one user he showed on ainimdstrative tools but not in mysql database