# Can I use the Membership provider in ASP.NET WebForms with my own User database? If so, how?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, custom-membershipprovider

I am looking for ways to implement **login** functionality in my ASP.NET WebForms application.
I know that I can use the default Membership provider which creates its own tables. I want to know if I can use my own schema for the database. **I don't want to install the Membership tables in my database or otherwise.**
I have an existing database with an existing structure that I cannot modify.

Or do I have to go the hard way and write my own membership provider like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2646176/4594699) suggests. If yes, then please be kind enough to point me to some tutorials about how to write a **basic** membership provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply customize the standard membership UserProfile table like in these examples: [(1)](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/06/22/ASPNET-Identity-20-Customizing-Users-and-Roles.aspx), [(2)](http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customize-users-profile-in-aspnet.html).

Or you could use your own existing data and map your users by ID or unique user name to the standard membership users. If you use this, keep in mind to keep it consistent (i.e. when handling users in your application).