# How to use a custom Users database table with asp.net membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership

My team and I are making a website that requires membership. Initially, we were going to code the membership from scratch using c# and mssqlserver but we want to save time and use the membership provided by ms asp.net. If so, how should we go to make our database and users table compatible with it?

Comment: If your DB is already on SQL Server, you can just [add the required table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/835185/529282) into your DB and point both the membership provider and your business logic to the created table.

Comment: So basically, I'll need the tables that comes with the membership for it to work? I won't be able to just use my own?

Comment: If you want to use your own table, inherit [MembershipProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) and you can use any table or any datasource imaginable while still benefit from the niceties of ASP.NET membership

Comment: Instead of implementing the dozens methods and properties, a middle way is to use the standard tables, but use triggers to 'sync' the required columns between your standar and custom table.